# Show spectrum of a bilateral shift is contained in a donut

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $W$ be a bilateral shift with weight sequence $(w_n) \in \ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z})$, for $w_n \geq 0$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

i.e. we have that $We_n = we_{n+1}$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, where $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis.

Suppose that there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\delta \leq w_n \leq 1$.

Show that $\sigma(W) \subset \{ z\in \mathbb{C}: \delta \leq |z| \leq 1\}$.

Things I've done:

I showed that if $\alpha \in \sigma(W)$, then we have $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|=\alpha \} \subset \sigma(W)$.

But I want to show that $\alpha \in \{ z\in \mathbb{C}: \delta \leq |z| \leq 1\}$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Define $W$ correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $We_n:=w_ne_{n+1}$ and the space is $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{Z})$, then $W=LD$ where $L$ is the right-shift operator and $D$ is the multiplier operator with sequence $(w_n)$. Note that both $L$ and $D$ are invertible.

Then $\|W\|\le\|L\|\|D\|=\sup_n|w_n|\le1$; hence $\sigma(W)$ is bounded by $1$.

Now repeat for $W^{-1}$: $\|W^{-1}\|\le\|D^{-1}\|\|L^{-1}\|=\sup_n|w_n^{-1}|\le\frac{1}{\delta}$; hence $\sigma(W^{-1})$ is bounded by $1/\delta$, and thus $\sigma(W)$ is bounded below by $\delta$.

Comment: May I ask how you got $W=LD$? I'm assuming that we have $Le_{n+1}=e_{n}$ and $De_n= w_n e_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  So we have $LDe_n = e_{n-1} w_n e_n $? Thank you!

Comment: @catsadnfish Obviously, he means $Le_n = e_{n+1}$, so it's actually the right shift. And what you wrote ($e_{n-1}w_ne_n$) doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @catsadnfish Many thanks to amsmath. I did mean the right shift operator. Note that $LDe_n=L(w_ne_n)=w_nLe_n=w_ne_{n+1}$ since $w_n$ is a scalar. The point of the answer is that it is valid for $\ell^\infty$ not just $\ell^2$.

Comment: When you said $\sigma(W)$ is bounded by $1$ from showing that $\| W\| \leq 1$, is it from the spectral radius formula? Thank you!

Comment: Also, for the last line. How did you conclude that $\sigma(W)$ is bounded below by $\delta$ from $\sigma(W^{-1})$ being bounded by $1/ \delta$? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @catsadnfish Yes, the spectrum is bounded by $\|W\|$. Similarly, $\sigma(W^{-1})$ is bounded by $\|W^{-1}\|\le1/\delta$. The reason is that $\sigma(W^{-1})=\{z^{-1}:z\in\sigma(W)\}$ (this is not hard to prove), so for $z\in\sigma(W)$, $|z^{-1}|\le1/\delta$.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean $We_n = w_ne_{n+1}$ and that your space is $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$. Then $W = SD_w$, where $S$ is the usual bilateral shift and $D_w$ is the diagonal matrix with the $w_n$ on the diagonal. So, $\|Wx\| = \|SD_wx\| = \|D_wx\|$, which implies
$$
\delta\|x\|\le\|Wx\|\le\|x\|.
$$
Similarly, $\|W^*x\|\le\|x\|$ and $\|W^*x\| = \|D_wS^*x\|\ge\delta\|x\|$.

From here you should be able to see that the spectrum of $W$ is in that annulus.

Comment: How does it follow that if $\|Ax\|\ge\delta\|x\|$ then $\sigma(A)$ is bounded below by $\delta$? For example, take $A$ to be the shift operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$: $\|Ax\|=\|x\|$ but it is not even invertible.

Comment: You're right. But the additional information that the same inequality holds for $W^*$ is enough. However, your proof is better. OP should check yours.